# Detecting visibility with overflow:hidden

Tags: jquery, css

I have a bunch of elements hidden due to having overflow:hidden on the parent element.  I made a jQuery function that adds to the margin to make a new set of elements visible when a user clicks.  However, I need a way to detect when the last element is visible so I can stop this feature from working once the end is reached.

The function I was using is this:

```
$(this).children('.Product').last().is(':visible')
```

I also tried:

```
$(this).children('.Product:last-child').is(':visible')
```

Both return false even when the last .Product element is visible on the screen.

Should this be working?
Is there a better way that I could be doing this?

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle that shows a moc-up of the situation?

Comment: The best way to do what you're trying is to just check when the margin size is at the size that it shows the last element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:visible` specifications says 'Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.' http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ I suppose it doesn't check if an element is into the view or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$(this).children('.Product:last').is(':visible');
```

If this doesn't work, try pasting the html code or creating a fiddle so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, `:visible` will return true if they elements has visibility, ie they aren't `display: none` or they are still effecting the dom's flow of elements.

What you're after is if they are in the current users viewport:

[See this Plugin: Viewport Selectors for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport)

Good Luck!